# Django running on an ECS task does not work. "Connection refused" or "No data response" when requesting the webapp

Tags: python, django, docker, gunicorn, amazon-ecs

I have some problems running **Django** on an **ECS task**.

I want to have a Django webapp running on an ECS task and accessible to the world.

Here are the symptoms:

- When I run an ECS task using Django `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` as entry point for my container, I have a `connection refused` response.
- When I run the task using Gunicorn using `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 my-project.wsgi` I have `no data` response.
- I don't see logs on CloudWatch and I can't find any server's logs when I ssh to the ECS instance.

Here are some of my settings related to that kind of issue:

- I have set my ECS instance security groups inbound to `All TCP | TCP | 0 - 65535 | 0.0.0.0/0` to be sure it's not a firewall problem. And I can assert that because I can run a ruby on rails server on the same ECS instance perfectly.
- In my container task definition I set a port mapping to 80:8000 and an other to 8000:8000.
  In my `settings.py`, I have set `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]` and `DEBUG = False`.
- Locally my server run perfectly on the same docker image when doing a `docker run -it -p 8000:8000 my-image gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0:8000 wsgi` or same with `manage.py runserver`.

Here is my docker file for a Gunicorn web server.

```
FROM python:3.6

WORKDIR /usr/src/my-django-project
COPY my-django-project .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["gunicorn","--bind","0.0.0.0:8000","wsgi"]
# CMD ["python","manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

Any help would be grateful!

Answer (score 1):

To help you debugging:

1. What is the status of the job when you are trying to access your webapp.
2. Figure out which instance the job is running and try `docker ps` on that ecs instance for the running job.
3. If you are able see the container or the job running on the instance, try access your webapp directly on the server with command like `curl http://localhost:8000` or wget
4. If you container is not running. Try `docker ps -a` and see which one has just stopped and check with `docker logs -f`

With this approach, you can cut out all AWS firewall settings, so that you can see if your container is configured correctly. I think it will help you tracking down the issue easier.
After you figuring out the container is running fine and you are able to request with localhost, then you can work on security group inbound/outbound filter.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was due to my database firewall. Your advice to run `curl http://localhost:8000` really helped me because it made me think about running my server manually in my ECS instance and test it "locally" via an ssh connection. Then I figured the issue out. Thanks for your support.